# Create a new column in sql with days added to current day

Tags: sql, datetime

I want to add a new column to an existing table and set its default value to the current day + 1, in other words, I want to set the date to tomorrow. How can I achieve this?
Im using the following code but it gives me syntax error

```
ALTER TABLE `user_details` ADD `tommorrow` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT DATE_ADD(NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for the same.

`NOTE`: `NOT NULL` comes after `DEFAULT`, order does matter else you will get `ORA-30649`

```
ALTER TABLE StackOverflow 
ADD tomorrow DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1) NOT NULL;
```

Sample Run
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the following SQL statement

```
ALTER TABLE user_details 
ADD tomorrow DATE DEFAULT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY') NOT NULL;
```